# Garbled characters when lauching jvisualvm from linux jdk

Tags: java, visualvm

I run jdk version 1.8.0_172 
exported the diskpaly then 
I run jvisualvm from $java_home/bin

the OS is oracle enterprise linux 7. 
I have garbled unreadeable characters.

[image: jvisualvm]

this is the output of 
jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Wednesday, July 11, 2018 11:55:35 AM CEST
>System Info:
  Product Version         = Java VisualVM
  Operating System        = Linux version 4.1.12-124.16.4.el7uek.x86_64 running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_172; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.172-b11; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_172-b11
  Java Home               = /opt/infra/java/jdk1.8.0_172/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (visualvm); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /root
  Current Directory       = /opt/infra/java/jdk1.8.0_172/bin
  User Directory          = /root/.visualvm/8u131
  Cache Directory         = /root/.cache/visualvm/8u131
  Installation            = /opt/infra/java/jdk1.8/lib/visualvm/visualvm
                            /opt/infra/java/jdk1.8/lib/visualvm/profiler
                            /opt/infra/java/jdk1.8/lib/visualvm/platform
```

is there something I am missing??

thank you

Comment: It looks to me like a problem with remote display. How does VisualVM look like when you run it locally? How does it look like when you use VNC?

Comment: never tried vnc I will update when I have.. did not know it was possible. i just used xming or other windows based xserver and launched from the linux server with the display exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should install missing fonts:

```
yum groupinstall fonts
```

Comment: This Fixed the problem.. huge thanks.. even with vnc it was not working..